# Using Mathematica to read .HDF (not .HDF5) metadata?

Tags: import

I am obliged to work with existing .HDF files. These contain metadata essential to my research that Mathematica (latest version) appears unable to access. Metadata listed on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF.html as being accessible are "Datasets" and "Dimensions", which I have read successfully. However, there are others such as, in my specific case, ""actual_range", "metrics" and "_Fill_Value" amongst others that I haven't been able to access. Is there a means within Mathematica to access all metadata?

HDF5 files are better supported, however project data is unavailable in this format.

Comment: Hi David, one option I can think of off the top of my head is to use `ExternalEvaluate`, Python, and `pyhdf` (aka `python-hdf4`) to make this happen... Be warned, though, `pyhdf` can be hell to install. For anybody interested, a large number of HDF4 files are available [here.](https://hdfeos.org/zoo/index_openLAADS_Examples.php) To be clear, I think you're trying to access the attributes of the HDF dataset, right?

Comment: Hi Carl. Thank you so much for your response. In answer to your query, yes, attributes of the HDF4 dataset.

Comment: In my limited experience with HDF5 files (not generic HDF) Mathematica's implementation is severely limited.  Smuggling the metadata in by some other means (as @CarlLange suggests) may be simplest.

Comment: Thanks Evan. I have the spec for HDF4 which details how metadata is handled. These are binary files of course, there are times I pine for ASCII.

Comment: Regarding HDF5, there should be some updates coming in version 12 that should significantly improve its support - there's a WTC2018 talk about it. @DavidH. I'm working on an answer that "smuggles" the metadata in, but it may take some time.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to convert your HDF file to HDF5 (for example using `h4toh5`: https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf5_tools/h4toh5/index.html) and then use `Import`.

Comment: Thank you again @CarlLange for your very, very thoughtful responses. Thank you too rafalc. One question though is whether all of the converted (h4 -> h5) data and attributes are available through Mathematica's .HDF5 import function, which evanb suggested leaves something to be desired. Very late here, will check in again in the morning.

Comment: @DavidH. unless your file uses some exotic datatype like Bitfield or Reference the HDF5 Importer should handle your file with no problems. Import of HDF5 has been completely rewritten in Mathematica 11.1, so maybe evanb meant the "old" Import. If you share one of your .hdf files with me, I can try if conversion to .h5 and then Importing in Mathematica works.

Comment: Thank you @rafalc. I might not be at liberty to share a file but will keep your offer in mind. I'll take a closer look at HDF5 functionality. Best wishes.

Comment: I did some work to access VData sets in HDF4. Maybe you can take a look and extend it to fit your needs: https://zeus.ph1.uni-koeln.de/staff/roellig/HDF4

Comment: Thank you Markus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by passing off all the actual work to python.

This requires that you have a python environment that has `pyhdf` installed. Honestly, the bulk of the work is going to be actually installing `pyhdf`, and I'm afraid that I can't help you there.

Assuming that you *do* have a python environment with `pyhdf` installed, the rest of this answer is for you.

What's going to happen is we're going to ask `pyhdf` for the results using `ExternalEvaluate`. If you've used python before the code is actually very simple.

First, we need to set up an ExternalEvaluate session:

```
session = 
 StartExternalSession[<|"System" -> "Python", "Version" -> "3.7.1", 
   "Executable" -> "/usr/local/bin/python3.7"|>]
```

Here I'm linking the session to my local python install that has `pyhdf` installed. If you got `pyhdf` using `conda` or similar, you'll want to find what the right path is for your executable.

Now that we have a session, we set up the `pyhdf` library:

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC"]
```

And now we can for instance read information about the datasets in the file. This returns a native Wolfram Language association.

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "hdf.datasets()"]
```

[image]

Now, let's use the `Land/SeaMask` dataset as an example, and read its attributes:

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "hdf.select('Land/SeaMask').attributes()"]
```

> `<|"valid_range" -> {0, 7}, "_FillValue" -> 221|>`

Fantastic. Well, there's your question answered, really!

We can make this a nice function like so:

```
readHDFDatasetAttributes[file_, dataset_] :=
 ExternalEvaluate[<|"System" -> "Python", "Version" -> "3.7.1", 
   "Executable" -> "/usr/local/bin/python3.7"|>, StringTemplate["
    from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC
    hdf = SD('`file`', SDC.READ)
    hdf.select('`dataset`').attributes()
    "][<|"file" -> file, "dataset" -> dataset|>]]
```

A final note: reading the dataset from python and reading it natively result in exactly the same data, which I find pleasing:

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "hdf.select('Land/SeaMask')[:,:]"] == 
 Import[hdffile, {"Datasets", "Land/SeaMask"}]
```

> `True`

Comment: Thank you so much for this inspiring reply. My colleagues are huge on Python. We work mostly with FITS files (astronomy). I don't know of anyone who's touched HDF. Hence, I relish the opportunity to have Mathematica employ Python even as just an exercise but I suspect it will be rewarding in my work too. Best wishes.

Comment: @DavidH. I'm glad you find it useful - if it's answered your question, please consider marking it as accepted! Last thing: [updated HDF5 and FITS support is coming in version 12.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cL0ZZLIQsss)

Comment: Thank you Carl, all.